# Open PDF document or google doc in Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

It's possible to open PDF document or google doc in A-frame webVR? Do you have some example? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Have you tried to create [minimal reproducible example!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try like this:

**1) Render the image on a canvas**

You could use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to render the pdf in a html `<canvas>`

**2) Use the canvas as a texture for an aframe entity**

```
<canvas id="pdf-canvas"></canvas>

<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane" material="src: #pdf-canvas"></a-entity>
```

Docs on canvas textures [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#canvas-textures).